# how ORM is supported by CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

does cakephp internally uses orm by default like grails.or it has to specified externally

Answer (score 2):

The ORM that is shipped with CakePHP is built-in, it's not an external library such as Doctrine or Propel that is added in the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to have a look at this http://book.cakephp.org/view/1000/Models